# New edge coloring problem in graph theory

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a simple graph. Consider the following edge coloring:

1. We are allowed to use repetitive colors on some edges incident to a vertex such that the result does not contain a sequence of length $3$ of one color.
2. The maximum different colors used for coloring the edges incident to a vertex is $s< \Delta(G)$.

> **Question 1:** Is Question 2 a known graph theory problem?
>
> **Question 2:** what is the smallest number
> of colors needed to color the edges of $G$ according to (1) and (2)?

Update.

**Remark:** Note that if $s=\Delta$ and without repetitive color then the problem reduces to usual edge coloring. this is useful for understanding this problem.

Comment: does a triangle count as a sequence of edges of length 3?

Comment: every sequence of edges, includes triangles  and three consecutive edges.

Comment: Sounds like there's no such coloring on a path or cycle of length $3$ or more---since $\Delta(G)=2$, every vertex has to only use $s=1$ colors on its incident edges, so you end up just using one color. Might be an interesting question for other graphs though.

Comment: It seems if this coloring possible then the smallest number of colors is $s+1$.

Comment: "Is this a known graph theory problem?" is hard to answer, since you have not actually stated a problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Presumably Question 2 is the problem, and Question 1 is whether Question 2 is a known graph theory problem. I think the OP should edit to clarify.

Comment: What do you mean by "repetitive colors" on some edges? The same color may be used on more than one edge? That would be expected. And what does it mean for $e_1,e_2,e_3$ to be a "sequence" of edges? Must the edges in the sequence be distinct? can they be adjacent?

Comment: I guess a "sequence of length $3$ of one color" is something like a monochromatic $P_3$ subgraph ($P_k$ being the path of length $k$). Perhaps Ramsey theory literature will have something about graph colorings that avoid "forbidden" subgraphs? Very classically it would be forbidden monochromatic complete subgraphs, $K_s$'s, i.e., monochromatic cliques of certain sizes. But surely there are papers or books about avoiding other monochromatic subgraphs.

Comment: I think that the condition $s<\Delta(G)$ is quite redundant, as one can add a star with many vertices (a $K_{1,N}$) to any graph. The edges of this star component can be colored with a single color.

Answer (score 2):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, I think this is essentially a star edge-coloring. The only difference is the added restriction $s<\Delta$ which slightly changes what is allowed at vertices of maximum degree.